# Active rigid bodies not colliding with passive ones

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision, rigidbody

I am trying to do pwnisher's community challenge. I downloaded base animation template (Blender). In blender the animation is playing just fine but when I add new objects for collision (rigid body : passive), the falling ball passes through it. Here are some settings that I'm using :

Ball :

- Rigid body type : active
- Collision shape : sphere

Cube :

- Rigid body type : passive
- Collision shape : mesh

I want the ball to collide with the cube. I tried dropping a object on other objects in another blend file and it works fine (I tried adding new objects and saw if those collide). I am totally new to simulations in blender. What could be the problem ?

.blend file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Ial5rG_0nimY8lnwLZTknmjENt2FtPb/view?usp=sharing

Solutions I've tried so far:

- Tried deleting all bakes.
- Tried changing steps per second from 10 to 60.
- Tried applying scale to the newly added cube (ctrl+A).

Comment: Hi. As it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please illustrate in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for replying. I'll add link to the blend file. I'll also edit the question and add solutions I've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The solution does not work for 2.82***

1. Select your ball, and in the timeline delete all keyframes (so the physics can do its work).
2. uncheck the "animated" flag here:

[image]

3. go to scene properties: hit "delete all bakes" in rigid body world
4. for your ball change sensitivity -> collision margin to 0

[image]

run the animation

you get this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Chris. Thanks for explaining in easy steps. But in 2nd step after deleting all keyframes the **animated** flag is already unchecked. I followed all the steps but still facing the same issue. Do you think there's a problem with my blender settings ?

Comment: Please start by downloading the file from your google drive. If you follow exactly my steps - it should work. Which Blender version are u using?

Comment: I did download the file again and follow your steps. Still no luck. I'm using Blender v 2.82.

Comment: ok, i will try with 2.82

Comment: @raiKage: you are right, i am sorry. It won't work in 2.82. Is is possible for you to update to a newer version?

Comment: Sure I'll update it. I just wanted to know that if its a bug or something was wrong with my settings. Thank you.

Comment: Your settings were all good - for me it looks like a bug, because with these changes i described above it worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127920/discussion-between-chris-and-raikage).